# delay when hiding soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-input-method

In my `Activity` I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a dropdown list. When the user selects an item, a new `Activity` is started. Since I have a lot of stuff in the next `Activity`, there's a delay of about 0.5-1s before it starts. I'm trying to hide the soft keyboard immediately after an item is selected:

```
   actvActionSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int position, long id) {
imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvActionSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
             //do stuff to prepare and start next Activity

        }
    });
```

However, the soft keyboard gets hidden appr. at the same time the next `Activity` starts. Where does this delay come from? Hiding the keyboard is the 1st thing I perform

Answer (score 2):

Note how you are getting `InputMethodManager` as a system service?

That means your call to `hideSoftInputFromWindow` is performed on a system `Service`, which means its always running in the background along side of your app, which means when you hide keyboard, its actually running in parallel as your app which is performing the activity create.

Comment: does it matter that I actually initialize it in onCreate() and not in the method I posted above? If not, any solution to avoid this delay on keyboard close?

Comment: What do you mean initialized it? One solution is to try to detect if the keyboard is shown before you launch your activity. See this post on how to detect keyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: I mean getting a reference to the corresponding system service: imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

Comment: It won't matter where you get the system service, when you call methods on background service, it will always be running seperately.